# Get rid of "\xa0" tag at the end of header in Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data set which contains some headers which end with no break space hex code. Below is my attempt to get rid of that but it still exists there.

Input:

```
files=[file1,file2,file3]
for f in files:
    for col in f.columns:
        col = col.replace("\xc2\xa0", "")
        col = col.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
    print(f.columns.values)
```

Output:

```
'Name' 'Date' 'rep_cur' 'Passenger Revenue\xa0' 'Cargo Revenue\xa0'
 'Other Revenue\xa0' 'Total Cargo & Other Revenue' 'Total Revenue\xa0'
 '% inc / (dec) to previous period' 'Employee Costs\xa0' 'Fuel and oil\xa0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.strip`:

```
l = ['Name','Date','rep_cur','Passenger Revenue\xa0','Cargo Revenue\xa0',
 'Other Revenue\xa0','Total Cargo & Other Revenue','Total Revenue\xa0',
 '% inc / (dec) to previous period','Employee Costs\xa0','Fuel and oil\xa0']
new_l = [i.strip() for i in l]
```

Output:

```
['Name',
 'Date',
 'rep_cur',
 'Passenger Revenue',
 'Cargo Revenue',
 'Other Revenue',
 'Total Cargo & Other Revenue',
 'Total Revenue',
 '% inc / (dec) to previous period',
 'Employee Costs',
 'Fuel and oil']
```

Comment: Hello, then how can I give all of these new string to my data frame's headers?

Comment: Just to `df.columns = new_l`

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Error appeared as: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 99 elements, new values have 1 elements

Comment: Never mind, It was me I didn't put comma between each since I use Pycharm and print doesnt leave comma. But it seems to be a manual solution because I have 90+ columns in each files and it make the code so long, do you have any solutions else?

Answer (score 0):

```
for col in f.columns:
    col = col.replace("\xc2\xa0", "")
    col = col.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
```

That does nothing to the actual `col` used for the iteration. That is pretty much equivalent to:

```
li = [1, 2, 3]
for n in li:
    n = n + 1
print(li)
# [1, 2, 3]
```

A decent IDE should show you a warning along the lines of "`n` (or `col` in your example) is redefined with no usage".

Instead you should use the tools pandas provide, for example [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a\xa0': []})

print(df.rename(lambda col: col.replace('\xa0', ''), axis='columns'))
```

Note that `.rename` returns a new dataframe. You can use `inplace=True` to change the original dataframe:

```
df.rename(lambda col: col.replace('\xa0', ''), axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

If you don't want to be so fancy you could replace the columns' names yourself (which is similar to what your original code tried to do):

```
df.columns = [column.replace('\xa0', '') for col in df.columns]
```

Comment: Hi, it shows error of : 
TypeError: rename() got an unexpected keyword argument "axis"
My code is :
file1.rename(lambda col: col.replace('\xa0', ''), axis='columns', inplace=True)
file2.rename(lambda col: col.replace('\xa0', ''), axis='columns', inplace=True)
file3.rename(lambda col: col.replace('\xa0', ''), axis='columns', inplace=True)
print(file1.columns.values)

Since I'm newbie in Python, could you rewrite the code based on mine, thanks

Comment: @DucHaNguyen does `type(file1)` output `pd.DataFrame`?

Comment: Also, I tried with
file1.columns = [col.replace('\xa0', '') for col in df.columns]
But it shows error: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 99 elements, new values have 1 elements